# Prove that the function $(\overset{-}{z})^2$ is not holomorphic in any open subset of $\mathbb{C}$.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Prove that the function $(\overset{-}{z})^2$ is not holomorphic in any open subset of $\mathbb{C}$.

Im not really too sure how to approach this question so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: How did you define holomorphic? What are the different equivalent conditions that you know?

Answer (score 3):

Treat $z \mapsto (\overset{-}{z})^2$ as the following function

$$f(x,y)= u(x,y)+ i v(x,y) $$

where $u(x,y) = x^2 - y^2 $ and $ v(x,y) = -2xy $.

$u_{x} = 2x$ aand $v_{y} = -2x$

Since $u_{x} \neq v_{y}$ on any open domain of $\Bbb{C}$

Therefore it doesn't hold Cauchy Reimann condition for holomorphicity.

Hence, $z \mapsto (\overset{-}{z})^2$ is not holomorphic on any open domain of $\Bbb{C}$.